# Is there a way to use your customized fields in reports created in MS project 2013?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013, reporting

I have some customized fields that I've created. I really need to find a way to use them while I'm creating customized reports in MS project, but I just see the built-in fields when I want to create the reports.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: What reports are you trying to run?  Any custom fields are not timescaled, so you cannot add them to the timescaled portion of a visual report.  Give us more of a hint which fields and which reports and we'll try to be more helpful.

Comment: Hello Julie, I want to have budget reports and resource reports. For my groups of tasks, I need to create a graph (bar chart basically) that shows let's say, how many hours of work each of my resources have put into that group of tasks. and for this, I use custom fields to group tasks...So I need to be able to see my custom fields in the reports and charts to add them, but I don't see them there. Is there a way?

Comment: The custom fields that are available in charts and graphs are limited.  You can create custom groups or custom filters and those will be available for grouping or sorting in the dashboard reports.

Answer (score 1):

More Custom Fields are available in 2016 but you still can't use Custom Text Fields in a Chart, but you can use Custom Numbers. Don't understand why you can have number but not text.